# How to make a significant compression of a Float32 raster file with gdal

Tags: three.js, raster, tiff, gdal

The question is pretty vague but that is what I mean. I have a 110GB raster file which is a combination of 20 other files resulting in a .tif file of whole Europe. I want to use its binary type in order to make a 3D terrain such as in [this blog](https://blog.mastermaps.com/2013/10/terrain-building-with-threejs.html) but the problem is its size. I have tried a few techniques with gdal such as:

```
gdal_translate 
  -co COMPRESS=JPEG 
  -co TILED=YES 
  input.tif output.tif
```

but apparently JPEG compression does not work with Float32 files. I prefer to save the negative values of the Float32 format but a 16 bit integer is also fine (which excludes all the Byte compressions). The best compression for Float32 files I found so far is using a PREDICTOR=3 as a compression expression but it is far from enough.

Is it even possible to achieve such a compression as I am describing it with gdal? What about other techniques?

Comment: I'm assuming you've went through [this](https://kokoalberti.com/articles/geotiff-compression-optimization-guide/) article? It's a very good and extensive guide to GeoTiff compression. Personal experience? Int16 + LZW + Predictor=2 works for me

Comment: Yes, I did, but the file size exceeds 10GB even after all that.

Comment: From 110GB to 10? Quite a feat, or a typo. Regardless, `JPEG` compression only works with `Byte` datatype. So if you can't scale your data to `Byte`, you can't use it.

Comment: No, I meant that it exceeds 10GB, if I achieve 10GB it would be a miracle at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've discovered, JPEG compression doesn't work for Floats (in fact, it's intended for integer RGB only since it lossily removes what is visually less perceptible).

`PREDICTOR=3` with `COMPRESS=ZSTD` and a high `ZSTD_LEVEL` is probably the best you can do truly lossless.

However, if you can tolerate a certain specific imprecision, and your GDAL version is at least 2.4, you can use `COMPRESS=LERC` or `LERC_ZSTD` with `MAX_Z_ERROR` set to the maximum imprecision (error through compression) that you can tolerate.

The implementation of LERC is slightly buggy in GDAL and can choke on NaN's, and maybe NODATAs or `inf`s. https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/3055 claims this was fixed in Oct 2020 but it still affected me today. As a workaround, you could convert to an Int16 by multiplying by scaling up by a fixed multiplier (representing 1) so that +-1 is within your target precision, and then using `COMPRESS=ZSTD` and `PREDICTOR=2`. Or even LERC again on the integer raster with an integer maximum Z error if you wish.

Example I just did:

```
gdal_calc -A "D2014 NDVI.tif" --outfile=out.tif --type=Int16 --calc=numpy.round(1000.0*A) 
gdal_translate -co "COMPRESS=LERC_ZSTD" -co "ZSTD_LEVEL=15" -co "MAX_Z_ERROR=5" -co "PREDICTOR=2" -co "TILED=YES" out.tif "D2014 NDVI lerc.tif"
```

You could doubtless combine into one line.  For me this reduced a 600 Mb Float32 TIF into a 120 Mb Int16 one, with integer scaled NDVIs -1000-1000, max error 5 (i.e. 0.005 before scaling). This is inline with what I've achieved with applying LERC_ZSTD to Float32 where it didn't choke.